# To Use java.util.Date object as Primary Key

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to use Date object as primary key. But I have an error. How can I use java.util.Date object as primary key ?

MyEntity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Date date;
...
```

Error log:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'myEntityRepository'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'routeMeetingDayRepository': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class
>   com.MyEntity] **does not
>   define an IdClass**

So, I have added @IdClass in my entity:

MyEntity:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Date.class)
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Date date;
...
```

New Error log:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2017-12-28
>   11:49:00.859 ERROR 23518 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: **java.util.Date has no persistent
>   id property**
>   ...
>   ...
>
> Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: **java.util.Date has no persistent
>   id property**
>   ...

Comment: And what did you learn when you googled that error message with your tags?

Comment: @pvpkiran No, that's not duplicate. It's a custom object on the link you share. I want to use java.util.Date

Comment: @pvpkiran and How can I add @ Embeddable into Date object. This is impossible. So that's not duplicate.

Comment: Put `@MappedSuperclass` on `MyEntity` class, that way its properties will be treated as persistent.

Comment: Check my [demo project](https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes) - I used there `LocalDate` as PK. Maybe it can help...

Comment: Thanks @Cepr0 .  That's a good project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it was easy to solve it.

Just add this   `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` before your PK.
Application will need to add a value into this field, because it is not auto-generated.

```
@Id
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
```